# How to adapt the text to a label?

Tags: java, swing

I would like the text taken dynamically from my database and inserted into a label to adapt to the size of the label. 
For example, given a label of certain dimensions, I would like to avoid the formatting of the text in "This text is too much ..." and to wrap.

Comment: Please provide what you have tired so far before asking for assistance, without it your question will be closed for lack of clarity or information.

Comment: You can use html tags in your text.